# why lock tokens are needed for multithreading programs

Tags: c#, .net, clr

Below is an example

```
public class Printer
{
    // Lock token.
    private object threadLock = new object();
    public void PrintNumbers()
    {
       // Use the lock token.
       lock (threadLock)
       {
           ...
       }
    }
}
```

but I still don't get the concept of a thread token, why is it necessary? is a thread token same thing as Semaphore in C? But for C programs, a Semaphore is just a integer?

Comment: It's a mutex (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion) for preventing race conditions (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition).

Comment: Unrelated: I think the recommendation is to make `threadLock` readonly.

Comment: Does the [C# Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement) help?

Comment: @llian so it is a binary semaphore which is a mutex. Isn't that a mutex a integer? how come a object can be a mutex?

Comment: @secondimage: it's not a binary semaphore. it's just a mutex. a binary semaphore can act as a mutex but not all mutexes are binary semaphores. most entities in c# are objects. semaphores are even implemented as a class/object (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphore?view=netframework-4.8.)

Comment: @Ilian  OK, so shouldn't it be a dedicated class in .net world to represent mutexes , how come I can just create a object or pass an instance variable to represent mutexes?

Comment: @secondimage It's actually just shorthand for using the Monitor class. Please read the manual: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement.

Answer (score 0):

`lock` is a mutex, and works like POSIX `pthread_mutex_lock` and `pthread_mutex_unlock` in C.

Only one piece of code is allowed to acquire a lock on a given object at once, so it's a way of synchronizing threads (not necessarily the best way, but that's a much more detailed and highly contextual answer).

---

As an example, the following code runs a couple threads at the same time:

- one increments each element of an array of numbers by 10,
- the other prints the contents of the array

```
var numbers = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

Task.WhenAll(
  Task.Run(() =>
  {
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
      numbers[i] += 10;
      Thread.Sleep(10);
    }
  }),
  Task.Run(() =>
  {
    foreach (var i in numbers)
    {
      Console.Write(i + " ");
      Thread.Sleep(10);
    }
  })
);
```

Since they run at the same time, the output is something like:

> 11 2 13 4 5 6 7 18 9 10

Some numbers are incremented, others are not, and it's different every time.

The same code with the loops wrapped in a lock, however:

```
object threadLock = new object();
var numbers = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

Task.WhenAll(
  Task.Run(() =>
  {
    lock (threadLock)
    {
      for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      {
        numbers[i] += 10;
        Thread.Sleep(10);
      }
    }
  }),
  Task.Run(() =>
  {
    lock (threadLock)
    {
      foreach (var i in numbers)
      {
        Console.Write(i + " ");
        Thread.Sleep(10);
      }
    }
  })
);
```

This only ever outputs one of the two things, depending on which loop acquires the lock first:

> 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20

or

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

There's no actual coordination between the two tasks, so which set you get (incremented or not) just depends on which happens to acquire the lock first.